# Form auto calculate answer to php

Tags: php, html

I have an autocalc running on a form and the total is shown through a div ID. I need to be able to somehow render the div ID answer into a php form mailer.

I’ve tried adding a hidden input field with the div ID.

```
            <div id="totalPriceTM">
            <input name="Score"  id="totalPriceTM" value=""   type="hidden" />
            </div>
```

No error messages but result not showing in email.

Comment: Show the JavaScript that stores the calculation result in the hidden input.

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique, don't use the same ID for the DIV and INPUT.

Comment: function calculateTotalTM()
{
    var cakePrice = inscriptionPriceTM() + getCakeSizePriceTM() + getCakeSizePrice1TM() + getCakeSizePrice2TM();
     
    if (cakePrice > 90){
var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPriceTM');
divobj.style.display='block';
divobj.innerHTML = "SELL";
}
    else if (cakePrice < 34){
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPriceTM');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "STOP";
}

Comment: Put the code in the question, it's totally unreadable in a comment.

Answer (score -1):

You should create different div name on your form.
for example :

```
<script>
function autocalc(x,y)
{
   a = x*y;
   document.getElementById(totalPriceTM).innerHTML  = a;
   document.getElementById(totalPriceTM2).value = a;
}
</script>

<div id="totalPriceTM">
<input name="Score"  id="totalPriceTM2" value=""   type="hidden" />
</div>
```

result will be show on div totalPriceTM and will be set the value of div totalPriceTM2